# Не получается сделать анимацию в Blender. Проблемы с действиями

Tags: анимация, blender

Пытаюсь создать два  действия открывания и закрывания дверей в  blender. Кубы взял для чистоты эксперимента.

Проблемы:

1. При создании маркера создается еще одно действие.
2. Когда двери открыты, я пытаюсь из этого положения сделать действие закрывания дверь, но не выходит.

Пример с ошибками на видео по [ссылке на youtube](https://youtu.be/jXTX_QcquFU)

Answer (score 0):

У вас два объекта, а Action вешается только на один. Чтобы сделать так, как вы хотите, нужно сделать арматуру с двумя костями, анимировать ее, а кубы привязать к арматуре. Тогда у вас будет один action на одной арматуре с ключами анимации на две кости, а не два как вы делаете